# Algorithm to find longest common substring

Tags: linux, bash, python, shell-script, algorithm

I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with a general solution to the following problem.

First a bit of context.

**End goal**: *set file permissions on all files and directories created by a rpm*

My plan was to get a list ff directories by doing

```
$ rpm -qlpv rpms/adf-endpoint.rpm  | grep "^d" | column -t
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /etc/adf-endpoint/jms
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /etc/adf-endpoint/jms/external-ssl-hsm
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /etc/adf-endpoint/jms/internal-ssl-hsm
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /etc/adf-endpoint/jms/internal-ssl-jks
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint
drwxr-x---  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/bin
drwx------  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/conf
drwxr-x---  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/lib
drwxr-x---  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/logs
drwxr-x---  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/temp
drwxr-x---  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  May  10  2019  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  May  10  2019  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/img
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/styles
drwxr-x---  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /usr/share/adf-endpoint/work
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /var/lib/adf-endpoint
drwxr-xr-x  2  adf-endpadf-endp  0  Dec  13  2022  /var/log/adf-endpoint
```

I get the last column by piping to  `awk '{print $NF}'` and get

```
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms/external-ssl-hsm
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms/internal-ssl-hsm
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms/internal-ssl-jks
/usr/share/adf-endpoint
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/bin
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/conf
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/lib
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/logs
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/temp
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/img
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/styles
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/work
/var/lib/adf-endpoint
/var/log/adf-endpoint
```

Of this data I want to get only these lines printed

```
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms
/usr/share/adf-endpoint
/var/lib/adf-endpoint
/var/log/adf-endpoint
```

So that I can do `chgrp -R` && `chmod -R` on those directories

**Question:**

An elegant clear way to solve this.
I would prefer a bash solution but it's not strictly nessesary

Comment: (1) Are you sure that the displayed URIs have no white space? Else `$NF` will fail. — I would prefer to select the files by `/.*$` (2) Is this an example or do you want to handle only this single rpm package? This is important as how can we be sure `./jms` exists.

Comment: @dodrg Yes I'm sure there are no whitespaces. It's one of a group of rpm's I'm familliar with.  But your way is safer and I will use your suggestion when I implement my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is that one `/etc/adf-endpoint/jms` instead of `/etc/adf-endpoint`? Who  created `/etc/adf-endpoint`? Because the rest is just `find / -path '*adf-endpoint' -type d`

But anyway, since you were asking for an algorithm to find the longest substring, this can be done in shell code because you can easily strip substrings from the front with `#` (or end with `%`). If there is nothing to strip, we have a new string.

Assumption: the input is sorted as it is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

substring() {

local list="/etc/adf-endpoint/jms
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms/external-ssl-hsm
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms/internal-ssl-hsm
/etc/adf-endpoint/jms/internal-ssl-jks
/usr/share/adf-endpoint
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/bin
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/conf
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/lib
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/logs
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/temp
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/img
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/webapps/ROOT/styles
/usr/share/adf-endpoint/work
/var/lib/adf-endpoint
/var/log/adf-endpoint"


local first=0 size=0
local var1="" var2=""
for var1 in $list
do
    if [ $first -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $var1
        first=1
        var2="$var1"
        continue
    fi

    size=${#var1}
    var1=${var1#$var2}

    if [ ${#var1} -eq $size ]
    then
        echo $var1
        var2="$var1"
    else
        continue
    fi

done

}

substring
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Nice use of `${var1#$var2}` and that. I have not yet internalized what the (for me) new things can really do. As for your questions. I can't use find because the files and dirs dont exist, it's just a list queried from a rpm package.  And as for "/etc/adf-endpoint/jms", I can only work with what querying the rpm gives me.